# Django and Rails - what should I expect in a Windows environment?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, windows, django, windows-7

I work in an environment that is totally .NET.

However, over the past few months I've been learning Ruby and Rails on the side and enjoying it very much.  I have been using Windows 7 to develop - along with Aptana - and so far things have gone better than I expected.  I have run into a few issues with gems on windows - various gems with event-machine dependencies often blow up on me while installing.  Also, deploying to Heroku can sometimes be an issue because of x86 references being put into Gemfile.lock.

The biggest issue though, is that there have been a couple of projects at work that could have been tackled quite well with Rails - except for the fact that all of our apps must run in-house on IIS.

I've recently been thinking of similar frameworks and languages such as Python and Django, and wondering (mainly just to satisfy curiosity):

**Would I have less - or more - issues developing with Python + Django on a Windows platform?**  (Especially running on Windows servers)

It would be great to get some input from those who have tried both, but if you could point out some benefits vs pitfalls to one or the other, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Developing Django apps on Windows will have some issues, but it's possible :) Like the same problem with some packages - you either need to compile it (and to compile it you need to install some environment, like MinGW or something), or you could get precompiled binaries. I can't remember now some blocker difficulties that'll make Windows+Django impossible. And small note from CO - it'd be better to develop something using the same environment that will be used to run this something.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to wonder if I should just get a Mac - or take the cheap route and install Ubuntu.  :)

Comment: This not a discussion forum. You should ask a specific question regarding Django on Windows; which I'll be happy to answer since I use Django on Windows at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Django on Windows Vista and it works very well. I am using sqlite, mysql and postgres.

mysql install is a bit tricky: I recommend to download the right binaries from the web.

I am using popular django apps and python modules without any problem. However, I've made a quick test with GeoDjango and noticed that it doesn't work out-of-the-box, mainly because of Postgis.

It's juste a little feedback. I hope it helps

Comment: Ok thanks, good to know there are folks using Django on windows in a work environment without a lot of issues.